# How much more space does Windows 10 Education take than Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10

I am being offered a (as in, one) upgrade to Windows 10 Education by my University, and while I feel I could benefit from some of the extra features on my daily driver, it only has 64GB of disk storage. I know I *can* install the upgrade on a disk of that size, but if the upgrade takes more than ~1GB I would prefer to upgrade my gaming laptop which has more storage.

Roughly how much more storage does the Education edition use than the standard Home edition?

Comment: The official online documentation that outlines the [Windows 10 Systems Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications) doesn't differentiate between the disk space needed for each different version.  If you are genuinely concerned, I would utilize the upgrade on our gaming laptop.  However, it sounds like you should be fine... just ensure that you perform a good [Disk Cleanup](https://www.howtogeek.com/264534/how-to-free-10-gb-of-disk-space-after-installing-a-new-build-of-windows-10/) afterwards.

Comment: @Run5k Hmm. I saw that too, but given how many more features the Education edition has, I thought the 20GB figure is more of a ceiling for usage.

Comment: @Run5k - They are confused between 32-not and 64-bit.  As you correctly point out the system requirements are that between Home/Professional and Enterprise/Education

Comment: @DividedByZero Which features?  There are very few Enterprise only optional Windows features.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Are you sure? The Microsoft website states that 32 bit Windows in general requires 16GB and 64 bit 20GB, but they don't seem to differentiate between editions...

Answer (score 0):

The space required by Windows 10 grows over time due to Windows Update, let alone actual usage.  If you have Professional or higher, you may be able to delay the updates.  I would leave at least 20 GB available just for Windows to work with comfortably, and just buy a bigger disk if needed.

Comment: That's fair, but what I am asking is how much extra space will be taken up directly *because* of the upgrade?

Comment: Please understand that this site is dedicated to making permanent reliable answers, and that if I took the time to calculate it as 0.8 GB today, and it was 0.9 GB tomorrow, then my answer would be worse than useless.

Comment: Please feel free to take the time to calculate it.  Wipe your PC, install one version of Windows 10.  Install nothing else.  Calculate its temporarily-stable disk usage after one day.  Wipe your PC, install the other version of Windows 10.  Install nothing else.  Calculate its temporarily-stable disk usage after one day.  Please make another answer with your findings.  Mention your scientific methodology for how you arrived at your answer.  Then, after a single round of updates for some modules and not others, it will be invalid.  Please understand that this is why I answered generally.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell there about the same. Education might be a couple gigs bigger cause of more features. But its nothing your really gonna notice. So I would highly suggest doing the upgrade. All windows 10 home and education needs is 16gb of HDD space. But overall there about the same size.